# Keyboard shortcut for vb.net to navigate between if and else

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio, keyboard-shortcuts

I have been coding in vb.net for last 15 days . But facing problem when i want to navigate between if else .

As in c#/c++  to know the closing brace  we generally use `cntrl +]` . Is there any equivalent shortcut present in vb.net ?

Please help since its really takes some time to get the corresponding else for if (specially when we have nested if and we are searching for else which correspond to 1st if .)

Thanks in advance .

Comment: If you need to use shortcuts to find an else block i would suggest to refactor your code instead(for starters: use methods).

Comment: @TimSchmelter Can you please give some solution for the above ?

Comment: A neat trick for partially solving this problem would be to click on the "If" for the if statement. VS will highlight any corresponding "else"s and the "end if." However, definitely  take @Tim Schmelter suggestion to heart. If you can't navigate your own if statements without being able to easily see where the "else" clauses and the "end if" is you should really consider re factoring your code.

Comment: I am using vs 2008 , so keyword is not getting highlighted .

Answer (score 0):

There are more than 140 shortcut keys in Visual Studio, and they are defined by YOU.  If you goto Tools>>Options and then go under Environment>>Keyboard, you will see all the shortcuts based on your laungauge preference. This link might help you [VS Shortcuts](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/da5kh0wa.aspx) but I couldn't find the shortcut you were talking about.  You might have to look at each shortcut under the C# options until you find the key-combination you are looking for, then you will know the NAME of the command. Then, look at the VB settings and see what it is there, or define it if not already.

Answer (score 0):

We cant navigate in vs 2008 or any earlier version . But from vs 2010 when we double click on any keyword it displays the rest keyword linked with it .

Answer (score 0):

Select the keyword "If' and highlight it, then press Ctrl+Shift+Up or Ctrl+Shift+Down to switch between if and else block.

Answer (score 0):

Select the keyword "If' it will highlight all 'if' 'else' keywords related to this, then press Ctrl+Shift+Up or Ctrl+Shift+Down to switch between if and else block.